# Facebook "re" authanticate

Tags: facebook

I have a site that user can login with facebook.

When user is logged-in he can do several actions. In one of this actions i want the user to re-authenticate (give his credentials again).

So is it possible when a user is already logged-in with facebook, to open facebook login dialog (or something similar) so that user can give his credentials again (or just the password)?

Comment: Why do you need that? PS: user **NEVER** gives you facebook password

Comment: i do not want user to give me his password. I want to re-open facebook login dialog, so user can re-authanticate, but without logout first. I want to repeat the login process

Comment: to be sure that the the user that will execute this action, is the actual user. It's complicated...

Answer (score 1):

> So is it possible when a user is already logged-in with facebook, to open facebook login dialog (or something similar) so that user can give his credentials again (or just the password)?

Client-side: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/client-side-re-auth/

Server-side: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-re-auth/

Comment: I' ve test the client side method, but no. The facebook login dialog popup only when user is logged out from facebook, else it throws a message in console `Log.errorin() called when user is already connected.` and execute the callback function. I want if the user is logged-in in facebook to re-open the login dialog an re fill the form with his credentials

Comment: Just tested it, and it works as expected. Conclusion: You’re doing something wrong.

Comment: OK, there seems to be a problem – if the user dismisses the popup, the response still reports back with status authenticated and an access token …

Comment: FYI, I tried filing a bug for the behavior I described in the comment before, but FB’s bugtracker seems to have a funny day: On submitting my bug report it tells me, “currently we are only accepting bug reports in English” – which of course is what i used … D’oh! Will try again later.